# docker-compose for portainer with traefik v2 gives "failure: unable to retrieve server settings and status"

Tags: docker-compose, traefik, portainer

I currently have a hard time updating my traefik v1 containers to v2. I set up a traefik container with automatic http->https forwarding. Now I want to get portainer running with the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
volumes:
  portainer: {}
networks:
  web:
    external: true
services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - portainer_data:/data
    command: |
      --no-analytics
      --data /data
      --admin-password "the_hashed_password"
      -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      web:
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.myserver.domain`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.middlewares=authportainer"
      # generate with: sudo docker run --rm -ti xmartlabs/htpasswd user password
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.authportainer.basicauth.users=myuser:my_hashed_password"
```

Now when I start the container with `docker-compose up` I get:

```
portainer_1  | 2020/04/19 16:10:04 Starting Portainer 1.23.2 on :9000
...
portainer_1  | 2020/04/19 16:10:04 server: Listening on 0.0.0.0:8000...
```

Accessing `http://portainer.myserver.domain` correctly forwards to `https://portainer.myserver.domain`.
After authenticating with `myuser`, an empty page is shown with a fading message toast "Failure. Unable to retrieve server settings and status". With traefik v1 the setup used to work. What I don't understand is if I need to do anything with port 8000 (which I didn't in the old working environment).

**How does one debug such a scenario?**
**What is wrong with my docker-compose file?**

P.S. For brevity, I omitted the traefik configuration file. If wanted, I will add it (it works with simple containers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After way too many hours I figured out two things:

1. **The browser was/is at fault here**
2. [latest is not what it says](https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375) (that one is unrelated but occurred to me during debugging)

Regarding the browser - I use Firefox 78.0.1 and always worked on docker from one specific machine. It seems that some data was cached that should not have been cached, with the **cache leading to the faulty page**. I don't know if portainer stored some data in the browsers cache (like cookies), but **making it forget about the site** ([see here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1059209)) **made portainer work normally**. Note that pressing `F5` or `Shift+F5` didn't work here, neither did restarting the browser.

If you encounter a similar issue, you can also **load the page in a private window**. Depending on your configuration of your brower, this should prevent it to use previously cached data.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar problem and could solve it by extending the router rule (see also the [Traefik documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/#rule).):

```
- "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.myserver.domain`) || (Host(`portainer.myserver.domain`) && PathPrefix(`/api`))"
```

This way, Traefik should now route the api requests of the Portainer front-end correctly.

Hope this helps you too!

P.S. Regarding your debug question, I figured this one out by inspecting the network interaction by the browser, which revealed that all calls to `portainer.myserver.domain/api/xyz` returned a 404 error.

Comment: The networking tab in the browser is indeed a good point. I will try your suggestion later and upvote if it solves the problem. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: I was wondering shouldn't the first condition also include the 2nd? if the host is `portainer.myserver.domain`, then why do we need another condition with the same host `AND` some other condition?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an caching problem.

1. Go to Dev-Console of your browser
2. open "web-storage"
3. remove local storage of your portainer url ( right click)

Answer (score 0):

**Removing basicauth middleware helped me to resolve the issue.**

Portainer for some reason doesn't work with Traefik's authentication middleware (at least with basicauth one).

This is pretty safe as Portainer has it's own authentication.